# Doesn't Faraday's law violate conservation of energy?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, electromagnetic-induction

Faraday's law says that if we have a changing magnetic field, there will also be an electric field (basically). I already know that both fields have energy. Is this energy given when accelerating the source of magnetic field (magnet for example)? Where does it come from?

Comment: These are very different questions, please choose one and make another post for the additional questions.

Comment: I am sorry. One question would be enough. It is my first question on the platform.

Comment: Do you know about Lenz's law?

Comment: Yes but It doesn't explain my question I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The energy density $\mathcal{U}$ is defined as
$$\mathcal{U}=\epsilon_0\frac{E^2}{2}+\frac{1}{2\mu_0}B^2$$
The continuity equation of energy given by
$$-\partial_t\mathcal{U}=\nabla \cdot \vec{\mathcal{S}}$$
where
$$\mathcal{S}\equiv \frac{\vec{E}\times \vec{B}}{\mu_0}\ :\text{Energy per unit area per unit time}$$

---

Consider as an example : Sinusoidal field applied to the coil. (Suppose the field to be in $z$-direction and coil to be in $xy$-plane.

$$\vec{B}=B_0\sin(\omega t)\hat{k}$$

As an exercise find $\vec{E}$ using  the symmetry of the system and
$$\nabla \times \vec{E}=-\partial_t\vec{B}$$
(Otherwise, See Example (Sinuaoidal B field) Page 358 Chapter 7 In Electricity and  Magnetism Purcell)

$$\vec{E}=-|E_0|\cos(\omega t)\hat{\varphi}$$
$$\rightarrow \mathcal{\vec{S}}= -|E_0|B_0\cos(\omega t)\sin(\omega t)\hat{r}$$
More specifically, see the direction of the poynthing vector which is inward and thus showing the  there is a flow of energy into the  system. Also as an exercise  find
$$\partial_t\mathcal{U}=??\rightarrow \text{Verify}\ =-\nabla \mathcal{\vec{S}}$$

Which confirms the energy conservation.

Answer (score 0):

Faraday says that when there is a change of flux linked to a circuit an emf is induced.

Imagine a single conducting ring and a magnet moving towards the ring.

An emf is induced in the ring (Faraday) and that results in an induced current in the ring which produces Ohmic heating in the loop as it has some resistance.

So the outcome is that heat energy is being produced but where does it come from?

It comes from having to **push** the magnet towards the ring, ie do work, because Lenz (note @M.Enns comment) tells you that the induced **current** will produce magnetic fields which will oppose the magnet moving towards the ring ie there is a repulsive force between the magnet and the ring carrying the induced current.

So the magnet might lose kinetic energy or have an input of work done by an external force ie you pushing.